# Admob get a conflict with Facebook`s SDK

Tags: android, facebook, admob

After init FacebookSdk manually in my appliction

`FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());`

When i play RewardedVideo of Admob,the app crashed:

Here is the crash log

> `01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002): Process: com.vikings.hl, PID: 32002
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lbolts/AppLinks;
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at com.facebook.appevents.internal.SourceApplicationInfo$Factory.create(SourceApplicationInfo.java:131)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker.onActivityCreated(ActivityLifecycleTracker.java:131)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker$1.onActivityCreated(ActivityLifecycleTracker.java:77)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:197)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1008)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6910)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bolts.AppLinks" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vikings.hl-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.vikings.hl-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.vikings.hl-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /product/lib]]
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>   01-05 17:27:47.780 E/AndroidRuntime(32002):     ... 18 more`

its seems "bolts.AppLinks" is belong to FaceBookSdk,when id didnt init FaceBookSdk,everything is ok,did anyone have meet this problem?